# Cordova-android version issue and camera plugin error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I installed the native camera plugin in my ionic project, and generated the apk, however when I run the plugin function the debug returns me an error "Native: tried calling Camera.getPicture, but the Camera plugin is not installed.", "Install the Camera plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera", ok I run the specified command and it gives me the following error "Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 9.1.0, failed version requirement: >=10.0.0" I updated cordova-android to version 10, however I try to install the plugin and it returns the same error.

Debug error
[image]

Terminal error when I install
[image]

package.json
[image]

Comment: try using system Terminal. and first uninstall platform. `ionic cordova platform rm android` then reinstall `ionic cordova platform add android@10.1.1`